# storyboard segue call order

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

So i am experimenting with segues and have just got the hand using `prepareForSegue` to get the destination controller based on an identifier and pass variables up(down) the chain. However i have encountered an issue where my current segue relies on the NSIndexpath from a uitableView, and the segue is activated on pressing uitableviewcell of said table. Problem is `prepareForSegue` is called before `tableViewDidSelect`, the only possibly solution i can think of is using a scheduled timer...which really is not ideal and a bit messy, can anyone witha  bit more know How on seagues and such to give me a hand here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i found my answer here [Storyboard segue gets called before UITableView's didSelectRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475365/storyboard-segue-gets-called-before-uitableviews-didselectrow)

essentially the answer i was looking for, is setting up a manual seague, basically a segue that only get's performed when called explicitly through code rather than action based.

Answer (score 0):

In prepareForSegue method you can get the current selected row by

```
[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row
```

This situation is described in details in Apple's 
["Your second iOS App" tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/). You can check out how the "sighting" property of a DetailViewController (in the tutorial) is being set when the segue from the MasterViewController to the DetailViewController is triggered. The segue is called "ShowSightingDetails".